# need help to overload the operator +

Tags: c++, overloading

so i want to overload operator + (C++) in my class matrices to use this instruction 
    m1 = m2 + m3

knowing that i have already overload th operator = but it crashes at execution
here is my code
class matrices:

```
#include "../include/matrices.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class matrices
{
    public:
        int taille;
        int **tab;
    public:
        matrices();
        matrices(int);
        matrices(matrices &);
        virtual ~matrices();
        void setTaille(int);
        int getTaille();
        void setVal(int, int, int);
        int getVal(int, int);
        friend istream& operator >> (istream&, matrices& ); //surcharge de l'opérateur >>
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const matrices& ); //surcharge de l'opérateur <<
        //void operator=(matrices&);
        matrices& operator=(matrices& );
        //friend matrices& operator+(matrices , matrices );
        friend matrices& operator+(matrices&, matrices&);
        friend matrices operator-(matrices);
        friend matrices operator*(matrices);
};

matrices::~matrices()
{
    //dtor
}

matrices::matrices()
{
    taille = 2;
    this->tab = new int*[taille];
    for(int i=0; i<taille; i++)
        this ->tab[i] = new int[taille];
}

matrices::matrices(int n)
{
    taille = n;
    this->tab = new int*[taille];
    for(int i=0; i<taille; i++)
        this->tab[i] = new int[taille];
}

matrices::matrices(matrices & m1)
{
    (*this).taille = m1.taille;
    tab = new int*[(*this).taille];
    for(int i=0; i<(*this).taille; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<(*this).taille; j++)
            this->tab[i][j] = m1.tab[i][j];
}

void matrices::setTaille(int n)
{
    (*this).taille = n;
}

int matrices::getTaille()
{
    return (*this).taille;
}

void matrices::setVal(int val, int n, int m)
{
    this->tab[n][m] = val;
}

int matrices::getVal(int n, int m)
{
    return this->tab[n][m];
}

istream& operator >> (istream& flux, matrices& m1)
{
    for(int i=0; i<m1.taille; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m1.taille; j++)
        {
            flux >> m1.tab[i][j];
        }
    }
    return (flux);
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& flux, const matrices& m1)
{
    for(int i=0; i<m1.taille; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m1.taille; j++)
        {
            flux << m1.tab[i][j];
            cout << "\t" ;
        }
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    }
    return (flux);
}

matrices& matrices::operator=(matrices& m1)
{
    delete this->tab;
    (*this).taille = m1.taille;
    this->tab = new int*[m1.taille];
    for(int i=0; i<m1.taille; i++)
        this->tab[i] = new int[m1.taille];

    for(int i=0; i<m1.taille; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m1.taille; j++)
        {
            this->tab[i][j] = m1.tab[i][j];
        }
    }
    return (*this);
}

matrices& operator+(matrices&  m1, matrices&  m2)
{
    matrices mtmp;
    mtmp.taille = m1.taille;
    mtmp.tab = new int*[mtmp.taille];
    for(int i=0; i<mtmp.taille; i++)
        mtmp.tab[i] = new int[mtmp.taille];

        if(m2.taille == m1.taille)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<mtmp.taille; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<mtmp.taille; j++)
                {
                    mtmp.tab[i][j] = m1.tab[i][j] + m2.tab[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return mtmp;
}
```

and this is my main fonction

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/matrices.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    matrices m1,m2,m3;
    cin >> m1;
    cin >> m3;
    m2 = m1;
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
    cout << "==== Affichage de la matrice ====" << endl;
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
    cout << m2;
    getchar();

    cout << "==================================" << endl;
    cout << "==== sommation des 2 matrices ====" << endl;
    cout << "==================================" << endl;
    m3 = m1 + m2;
    cout << "==================================" << endl;
    cout << "==== matrice m3 matrices est: ====" << endl;
    cout << "==================================" << endl;
    cout << m3;
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Don't you get a warning about returning a reference to a local variable?

Comment: noo there is just a crach during the execution

Comment: Have you used a debugger to determine where the cash is occurring?  If so, which line is causing the crash?  If not, why not?

Comment: yes i did it, but ididnt understand what that mean 

Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Build succeeded
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Users\North-Side\Documents\cc\
Adding source dir: C:\Users\North-Side\Documents\cc\
Adding file: bin\Debug\cc.exe
Starting debugger: 
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb 6.8
Child process PID: 9096
In __cxa_throw () ()
Debugger finished with status 0

Answer (score 3):

You must be either using a compiler that does not give you a warning about this, or are ignoring the warning:

```
matrices& operator+(matrices&  m1, matrices&  m2)
{
    matrices mtmp;
    ...
    return mtmp;
}
```

The code is a big problem:  you are attempting to return a reference to an automatic variable.  By the time you attempt to use the reference, the object no longer exists.

You should declare your overload this way:

```
matrices operator+(const matrices&  m1, const matrices&  m2)
{
    matrices mtmp;
    ...
    return mtmp;
}
```

Which will also require you to change your friend declaration:

```
friend matrices operator+(const matrices&, const matrices&);
```

That way you are returning a *copy* (since you aren't changing `m1` and `m2`, you should declare their references as `const`).

Additionally, you should look into the copy-swap idiom for your copy-assignment operator as doing something like `m1 = m1` would cause a crash in your current code.  As a corollary to this point:  you do not declare a copy-constructor, so when you do something like `matricies m2 = m1`, it is doing a shallow copy (the default implementation of the copy-constructor).  So `m2`'s pointers are pointing to the data in `m1`.  When you destruct `m1`, `m2` contains dangling pointers ... which will cause a heap corruption (deleting already deleted memory).

A lot of your memory issues (and they are many) go away simply by switching to `std::vector` or `std::array` (depending on how you want to define your class) instead of trying to manage the memory yourself.  A simple (incomplete) example:  http://ideone.com/VVqvGy

Comment: thanks jack for that explanation,
but when i change the prototype it gives that error:
  error: no match for 'operator=' in 'm3 = operator+(const matrices&, const matrices&)(((const matrices&)((const matrices*)(& m2))))'|

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Comment: i change matrices& operator+(matrices&  m1, matrices&  m2) to  matrices operator+(const matrices&  m1, const matrices&  m2)   and also the friend declaration

Comment: Change your copy-assignment declaration to use a `const matrices&` parameter instead of `matricies&`.

Comment: yeees it works, look thank you so much zac u r awsome :)

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with your class.

1. You dynamically allocate memory in the constructor, but you don't
   free it in the destructor. This is a memory leak.
2. In operator=, you free memory that you allocated with `new[]` with `delete` (notice the lack of[]): This is undefined behavior, and does random stuff. You should also delete all dynamically allocated memory, not just the 'top level' - the same way that you allocate it in a loop in the constructor, you should free it in a loop, and use `delete[]`.
3. Your `setTaille` method is pointless: It will only destroy your data, lead to memory leaks and inconsistency in your data. It should be either completely reworked, to reallocate and copy the contents of the current matrix to allow the size to be set, or removed altogether. (I can honestly not imagine a use case for it)
4. in `operator+`, you should check that the size of the matrices are the same, before performing any allocations. You should make a decision what should the result of adding non-compatible matrices be (it's a tough choice).

The error in your code most probably comes from error number 2.

EDIT:
I spotted another problem that I overlooked:
In your `matrices& operator+` function, you return a reference to a auto variable (that is, memory on the stack). This is illegal: The moment that you leave the function, this memory becomes garbage. You most probably want to return a copy of the constructed matrix(Use `matrices operator+`